# Rails 4 app... in development environment javascript not firing unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am having an odd issue with my first rails4 app where my page javascript is not firing unless I reload the page.

This is true for both my asset pipeline JS and also inline with content_for JS.

in my /assets/javascripts/cars.js file:

```
$(function(){
    $("#car_car_make_id").on("change", function(){
        //SET MODELS
        $.ajax({
            url: "/car_makes/" + $(this).val() + "/car_models",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function(data) { model_list(data) })
        .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
    });
});

function model_list(data) {
    $("#car_car_model_id").empty();
    $.each(data, function(i,v){ 
        $("<option />").val(v.id).text(v.name).appendTo("#car_car_model_id");
    });
    //ON COMPLETE SHOW
    $("#car_model_div").show();
}
```

inline in page with content_for:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('yt_vid', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: '<%= @timeslip.youtube_id %>'
        });
    }
</script>
<% end %>
```

Both of these only fire if i refresh the page.

For example, if i click a link to the page with the youtube video it will not load. but if I refresh it will. Same with the asset pipeline script, it only makes my ajax call if i reload the page first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks like a side effect of the new [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) feature. When you click a link, the page isn't being reloaded -- it's just having its `<body>` loaded by an AJAX request. So:

In the first case, the `$(function{ ... })` isn't being run because `document.ready` is only fired on the first page load, not reloading the body.

In the second case, the `<head>` isn't reloaded with turbolinks, just the body. So you're left with the old `<script>` and it isn't rerun!

Check some of the options for turbolinks, like [jquery.tubrolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).

Comment: I disabled turbolinks and that was causing the issue. However, I am thinking that might not be the best solution to the problem. I will research it further and see if there is a way to make my code work with turbolinks. thank you

Comment: I ended up trying adding the jquery.turbolinks gem then adding it to the JS manifest. This fixed the doc ready script. However, this still didnt make the content_for javascript work. So I then moved my content_for to write inside the body tag, however, this still didnt resolve the content_for issue. I ended up going back to disabling turbolinks

Comment: Why do you need to include javascript in content_for? Why not use the asset pipeline and let the browser cache all the javascript at once?

Comment: because i only need the youtube iframe API to be used on the show view in one page of the site. Why would i want all that extra weight when its only used in one place

Comment: With turbolinks and asset pipeline it wouldn't make much of an owerweight. 'Cause first of all all your CSS and JavaScript will be loaded once withought any nead to reload them on every request. What's more important - the browser will probably cache all that data, so even withough turbolinks it wouldn't be that much differnce.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem for me in a Rails 4 and solves it the solution of rmosolgo.

First add jquery-turbolinks gem

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

Add to application.js (as I saw at https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
.
.
.
//= require turbolinks
```

And works perfectly!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution by now is to use the `jquery-turbolinks` gem. Just add it to your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` and then add `//= require jquery.turbolinks` to your `application.js` file right after the jquery requirement.

Btw, it's best to move the turbolinks requirement to the bottom of that stack.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above (2nd one in response to rmosolgo) jquery-turbolinks fixed half the problem. but did not fix the content_for javascipt, even when i moved the yield inside the body tag

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the order here, @almaron. I was having issues and once I made sure `require turbolinks` was before `require jquery.turbolinks` I was in business

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, not a real solution: use target='_blank' for the url directed to that page, js will be loaded and fired correctly without extra gem.

Here is the same problem of mine:

I used a different approach to add page-specific js in the head, like this
`<%= javascript_include_tag "js_for_a" if

controller_name == "c" && action_name == "a" %>`
In js_for_a.js, I have something like this:
`$(function(){...})`

When the page is requested from a page not containing "js_for_a", this js file will not be loaded.

After I install gem 'jquery-turbolinks' and add `//= require jquery.turbolinks`in the right place, the js will not load. But if cached by browser before, it will be fired.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Please do not include questions in an answer.