# Rails: No route matches [PATCH]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran into a very strange bug in my Rails app: Whenever I try to submit a form I get the error `No route matches [PATCH] "/business_cases"` (in this case). But after clicking the "Back"-Button in my Browser and filling out + submitting again, it works fine. As this error appears not only in this specific model but almost every other I'm quite lost.. Here is the example.

routes:

```
      business_cases GET    /business_cases(.:format)             business_cases#index
                     POST   /business_cases(.:format)             business_cases#create
   new_business_case GET    /business_cases/new(.:format)         business_cases#new
  edit_business_case GET    /business_cases/:id/edit(.:format)    business_cases#edit
       business_case GET    /business_cases/:id(.:format)         business_cases#show
                     PATCH  /business_cases/:id(.:format)         business_cases#update
                     PUT    /business_cases/:id(.:format)         business_cases#update
                     DELETE /business_cases/:id(.:format)         business_cases#destroy
```

routes.rb:

```
root 'dashboards#index'
get "index" => "pages#index"
resources :users, :orders, :sales, :business_cases
```

controller (FYI: I use cancancan):

```
class BusinessCasesController < ApplicationController
 load_and_authorize_resource
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def index
 end

 def show
 end

 def new
 end

 def edit
 end

 def create
   respond_to do |format|
     if @business_case.save
       format.html { redirect_to business_cases_url, notice: 'Business case was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @business_case }
     else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @business_case.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
 def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @business_case.update(business_case_params)
        format.html { redirect_to business_cases_url, notice: 'Business case was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @business_case }
      else
       format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @business_case.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  end

 def destroy
   @business_case.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to business_cases_url, notice: 'Business case was successfully destroyed.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
 end
```

model:

```
class BusinessCase < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :description, :presence => true
end
```

form (shorten):

```
<%= form_for @business_case, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "X-Sell" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing an update action in the controller?

Comment: Sorry, didn't included the def's

Comment: From which view are you posting the form, edit/new?

Comment: Maybe you have JS that changes HTTP method of the request?

Comment: The reason could be missing `:id` attribute value, I think `@business_case` is `nil` when you're invoking `edit` action.

Comment: @nbon a "New" action.

Comment: @Mareq. Propably `@business_case` is nil everywhere... This instance variable is in `if`, but it's not instiantated anywhere.

Comment: @Harakiri what does `@business_case.new_record?` return in `new` action?

Comment: @PatNowak CanCancan: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions handles that for me

Comment: @Harakiri if `@business_case` is a new record then the form_for should result in a post method. Try inspecting your resulting HTML form and see what value the method attribute gets. If you have a new record but a PATCH/PUT method then something seems fishy.

Comment: @MarekLipka the `new` and any other action works, as long as I just hit the "back" button in my browser.

Comment: @Harakiri So you go to `new`, fill the form, press submit button and you get this error, right? Please tell me what does `@business_case.new_record?` return in `new` action.

Comment: @nbon it's a post mehtod `<form class="new_business_case" id="new_business_case" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/business_cases" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">`

Comment: @MarekLipka absolutely correct. Where do I check this? Sorry I'm still a newbie to Rails :(

Comment: @Harakiri you have post. So again my suspicions goes to JS intercepting the request and doing it with changed http method. Do you have any custom JS?

Comment: @MarekLipka just found out that it also works fine at the first attempt after I reloaded the form with `CTRL+R` just after the page loaded. Seems to be a caching issue?

Comment: @Harakiri so this problem occurs after you post the form with invalid input, get the form again (directly after posting) and post it again?

Comment: @MarekLipka Not exactly. I click on "add new business case" (localhost/business_cases/new) and refresh the page immediately. This solves the problem and the first form-post gets saved. No errors. So it seems like the page doesn't get loaded correctly at the first place.

Comment: @Harakiri do you use turbolinks?

Comment: @MarekLipka Yes. I do. My application.js contains: 
//= require jquery   
//= require jquery.turbolinks   
//= require turbolinks   
//= require jquery_ujs   
//= require bootstrap-sprockets   
//= require underscore   
//= require dependent-fields   
//= require nprogress   
//= require nprogress-turbolinks   
//= require autocomplete-rails   
//= require_tree .

Comment: Disabeling turbolinks did it for me. [I'm not the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18524461/5243191) who had this issue.